# Unable to login in Virtual Machine in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: login-screen

I am using Virtual Machine Manager in Ubuntu 15.10. When I try to login after giving correct username and password the system is showing again the login screen. I can not use hot key because whenever I pressed hot key it always go to host machine not the guest or virtual machine.

Comment: This happens after an ubuntu update or installing a package that messes with your ubuntu. Have you installed anything recently?

Comment: Yes , I have installed android sdk and emulator. What should I do now any solution to this problem???

Answer (score 0):

1. CTRL + Alt + F1 in the Login screen to access terminal
2. apt-get remove --purge < full name of the package you just installed)
3. whereis < full name of package >
4. manually remove everything related to that package
5. sudo reboot

Comment: Thank you but if I press CTRL + Alt + F1 then it takes for host machine not the guest machine. I need solution for virtual machine. I want to retain the installed package.